# Share code related to a quesiton in a SCM

Tags: feature-request, collaboration

It would be nice if source code could be shared along with a specific question with the folowing benefits:

- no need to copy pase and format a lot of code into stackoverflow
- better possibility to export source code to resue it
- better management of revisions

I think a concretly something like git would best suite for this purpose. A git repository could be associated with each question. For each answer a clone could be created

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea, but I suspect it's not appropriate in the majority of cases, as (in an ideal world), the issues being explored should be expressed in the most minimal way possible.

i.e.: You don't want to have to wade through a heap 'o' source code when a small "use case" can illustrate the problem.